# Redirect to the same page after add to cart is clicked

Tags: php, woocommerce

not sure if this is the best option but I would like not to leave the page that the add to cart button is on. In order for more items to be added, I would like to add to cart and stay on the same page. I run into problems with variable products when I add to cart.

I have added some code to the functions php to send the person back to the referring site not sure if this is the best way to do this.

```
//redirect to the same page
  /**
 * Set a custom add to cart URL to redirect to
 * @return string
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
    return (wp_get_referer() ); 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

expected to stay on the same page when adding to cart button is clicked with simple and variable products. I also would like to have the notice shown on the same page.

Comment: What? Why do you want to redirect to the SAME page? :p

Comment: you probably should read into [DOM manipulation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and sending requests with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request)

Comment: The goal is to add to cart without leaving the page that the end user is using as I have thousands of products and people are purchasing from the archive pages. The redirect allows the items to be added to the cart without using an ajax add to cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("Location: $referer");
```

Comment: Not sure I follow this one, can I add it to the php in that format?